# ActionController::UnknownFormat (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby

I am creating a Ruby on Rails application where I render my 'new.html.erb' (in my klass controller) and on top of it render my partial '_select_previous.html.erb,' also, I have a 'link_to' to switch back and forth from one to the other. However, when I try to start my project at the 'index.html.erb' and then use a 'link_to' to go to the new file, it shows me that error above.

I am using jQuery to do the switching from one view to the other.

Here is my new.html.erb:

```
<p> Or select from the previous created classes <%= link_to "here", 
new_klass_path, id: "link_to", :remote => true %> </p>

<div id="previous">
   <%= render :partial => 'select_previous' %>
</div>

<div id="content">
 <!-- Ruby form -->
</div>
```

This is my klasses controller:

```
def index
    @klass = Klass.all.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    #import_klasses(@klass)
end

def new
    @klass = Klass.new
    #saved = @klass.save
    #@klass.save!
    #if saved
       #s1 = Student.last.id
       #k1 = Klass.last.id
       #@enrollments = Enrollment.new(student_id: s1, klass_id: k1)
       #binding.pry
       #@enrollments.save!
     #redirect_to :controller => 'enrollments', :action => 'index'
     #flash[:alert] = "Class Created"
  #end
#end

  respond_to do |format|
     format.html {}
     format.js
  end
end
```

And this is my show.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#days").hide();
$("#grade").hide();
$("#class").hide();
$("#all").hide();
$("#previous").hide();

$("#link_to").click(function () {
    var count = $(this).data("count") || 0;
    if(count == 1)
    {
        $("#content").hide();
        $("#previous").show();
    }
    else if(count == 2)
    {
        $("#content").show();
        $("#previous").hide();
        count = 0;
    }

    $(this).data("count", ++count);
});
});
```

Thank in advance for any help you may provide me.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], with emphasis on the word *minimal*? I highly doubt that it requires **464 lines of code** to describe your problem.

Comment: Does that work for you @TomLord?

Comment: Could you at least show us the incoming request (copy from your server output) and the full error stack.

Answer (score 0):

My last attempt, as I am out of my depth it seems. Use this along with your original code, files unrenamed. Leave your js file where it is.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.js do
        redirect('/assets/show.js')
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @CristianPolanco use the same code you had before, but rename show.js to new.js, and make sure new.js is in the same folder as new.html

Comment: My apologies, I did not read the next part. My javascript is called show.js. I will surely do that then.

Comment: in fairness i wrote it while you were still responding to me :p

Comment: Hahah, do you think I should name my js 'new.js' instead? Because it is still showing the same error.

Comment: make it `new.js.erb` so that ruby can recognize it

Comment: Right now my js file is my assets folder. Should I move it to my views folder? Where my new.html.erb is?

Comment: Ohhh let my change my answer

Comment: In this link: [here](https://imgur.com/a/GWcVf7P) is what the compiler tells me when I try running it.

Comment: @CristianPolanco No JavaScript that is referenced in the controllers should always be in the `app/views/some_dir` directory. Only assets should be in the assets folder. JavaScript can be an asset or a view, but when it needs to pass through the controller it means you have a chance to interpret server objects (using erb or coffeescript) which in turn makes it a view.

Comment: @JohanWentholt, I am not understanding (at least I think), but anything that I have in show.js I should put in a new.js.erb file?

Answer (score 0):

Though I really appreciate all the effort that has been put towards solving this question, I must advice that I found the solution to the problem.

The error was on my index.html.erb, which I did not put because I thought it had nothing to do with the problem. My index looked like this:

```
<div>
    <%= link_to "Create new class", new_klass_path(@klass) %>
</div>
```

The unknown format error came because it did not know what "@klass" was; or so I believe. As soon as I took it away, the transition from one page to the other went smoothly. Moreover, it looks like this know:

```
<div>
    <%= link_to "Create new class", new_klass_path %>
</div>
```

If this pisses anyone off, I deeply apologize. I really appreciate everyone's help. I am going to try to level up quickly, to give you guys checks for useful answers.